# When I call the api results, why does my column order change in results in R?

Tags: r, tibble

im new to R and trying to understand tibbles. Below, I have called fields in a particular order but as you see in my final output, the order completely changes. how do i maintain the order set in fields      = c("click_view.gclid","ad_group.id","campaign.id","segments.date") for my final output to reflect the same order?

library(rgoogleads)

```
#Authorization
gads_auth('gyygyg@gmail.com')

# Notes about authorization process:
# Run this command to check where they are cached: gads_auth_cache_path()
# You must check the box next to "Manage your AdWords campaigns" before clicking Continue.

# set manager account id

gads_set_login_customer_id('764-xxx-357x')

# set client account id

gads_set_customer_id(c('xxx-534-x284', '442-xxx-xxxx'))


facts<- gads_get_report(
  resource    = "click_view",
  fields      = c("click_view.gclid","ad_group.id","campaign.id","segments.date"),
   date_from   = Sys.Date(),
   date_to     = Sys.Date()
  #where       = "ad_group.status = 'ENABLED'
)
> facts
# A tibble: 1,435 x 4
   campaign_id ad_group_id  date       click_view_gclid                                                                   
   <chr>       <chr>        <date>     <chr>                                                                              
 1 10966159101 109491422823 2022-02-25 Cj0KCQiAmeKQBhDvARIsAHJ7mF4-EZvexiV-uobRzHwUuma6AK80svv6IbAuf2Sv450vKQKNV1WxwrkaAn~
 2 10966159101 104824558530 2022-02-25 Cj0KCQiAmeKQBhDvARIsAHJ7mF4-TrYslOvZtdeLqJzUyZEQjewhIXQ_1-OEfswCCLmNW_yGvlOFWYYaAt~
 3 10966159101 104824558530 2022-02-25 Cj0KCQiAmeKQBhDvARIsAHJ7mF4-hSWzXVaslwIT-F4IyrxcHdg0arU4roh68sEHvVVhNjBFQ-X6HMUaAj~
 4 10966159101 104824558530 2022-02-25 Cj0KCQiAmeKQBhDvARIsAHJ7mF4-kEZzoWDYOygen8l8aq3juQQQs7uQ5RsaR3mV56m5Whc3aBBNkHIaAh~
 5 10966159101 104824558530 2022-02-25 Cj0KCQiAmeKQBhDvARIsAHJ7mF4-uo33yCu-iBwcEkWRFfphO1ANAFTwrFEHwo-rsqw3Z5ZUBOC_ctMaAh~
 6 177373599   66592420944  2022-02-25 Cj0KCQiAmeKQBhDvARIsAHJ7mF4-vn8piOytXTxdss29LU8nmLi2slenQS_fZ41mfbBzQO6c10hFBikaAu~
 7 10966159101 104824558530 2022-02-25 Cj0KCQiAmeKQBhDvARIsAHJ7mF4-wbtYPjm1kZ4x6S9S1jOWAB3PS1Ih68lDs81B3QbeCjqwoSo3IxIaAk~
 8 10966159101 110335731309 2022-02-25 Cj0KCQiAmeKQBhDvARIsAHJ7mF400K6LdBTH4Dnqo8kP0W-okuXL6vyT8p0sxfjZRKHXpeO_FbWgNm8aAs~
 9 11844592263 114841439683 2022-02-25 Cj0KCQiAmeKQBhDvARIsAHJ7mF40PCmP5GG6pBE6kw76F9aWuRQGFU_fQ7_S2N57vLJlMVRpY38uXVsaAr~
10 10966159101 113535151649 2022-02-25 Cj0KCQiAmeKQBhDvARIsAHJ7mF40UsG8bC7xjDObVGPXOC7_zcasmv9KevgKgKPI9if4fZj-JzVBWEIaAl~
# ... with 1,425 more rows
```

Comment: the api probably has a fixed return order - just reorder the columns after returning the data

Comment: thanks @calum you . any method to reorder within the code? i have too many lines of codes of which this is one subset call. so i showed it as example. will make changes to others accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Set your `fields` vector prior to calling `gads_get_report`, and then use `relocate`

```
api_fields= c("click_view.gclid","ad_group.id","campaign.id","segments.date")

tbl_fields = c("click_view_gclid", "ad_group_id","campaign_id","date")

facts<- gads_get_report(
  resource    = "click_view",
  fields = fields, 
  date_from   = Sys.Date(),
  date_to     = Sys.Date()
) %>% relocate(tbl_fields)
```

Comment: i get an error Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Columns `click_view.gclid`, `ad_group.id`, `campaign.id`, and `segments.date` don't exist.

Comment: okay, so the api call sets the fields as above, but returns a tibble with different names (`campaign_id, ad_group_id,date,click_view_gclid) ?  Do you want to use those names, but in the order corresponding to their similar names in `fields`?  If so, you can try the edit. The point is is that you can use `relocate` as suggested by @Calum